# Is there a JavaScript (or jQuery) shortcut for "function(){return false;}"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To prevent actions from happening, I frequently type

```
function(){return false;}
```

Is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could declare a named function like this:

```
function always_false() { return false; }
```

then use `always_false()` wherever you would have previously created the anonymous function.

Comment: I'm thinking call it something shorter like ff() (bad name I know) and so that it's even shorter but this seems like the right idea.

Comment: Oh, "always_false" would be the actual listener?

Comment: then I would expand that, since he's using jquery to: function always_false(e){e.preventDefault();}

Answer (score 2):

I often have a ["no op" function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) defined at the top of my common js file:

```
function nop() { return false }
```

I use it whenever I need a "do nothing" or a "cancel event" handler (eg `div.oncontextmenu = nop`). In IE this has the added benefit that memory does not leak when creating similar [anonymous] functions on the fly and assigning them to event handlers. At least that's what [IE Drip](http://www.outofhanwell.com/ieleak/index.php?title=Main_Page) tells me.

Comment: return false; doesn't "cancel event"s.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut(*ECMAScript 2015*):

```
_ => false
```

Or, simply press 5 keys:

```
_=>!1
```

But I'd rather recommend you to use the below for non-jQuery *Event* handlers.

```
event => event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel an event default action by using the preventDefault method:

```
$("form").bind("submit", function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really think that's too much typing?

Why not have a global variable named `f` set to `false`, and use `function() {return f;}`

Comment: function f() { return false; }

Comment: Seems like a false economy :-7

Answer (score 0):

Just set the event handler to null. This is cleaner than assigning to a "return false" function IMO because it removes the event handler altogether.

myButton.onclick = null;